# Python library for computing spatial derivatives of optical flow

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, opticalflow

I'm trying to compute a differential image velocity invariants (e.g. curl, divergence, deformation, etc) from a video using OpenCV in Python. To do that, I need to compute the spatial derivatives in the x,y directions of the optical flow. Unfortunately, OpenCV only seems to supply the APIs for computing optical flow, not its derivative.

**Are there any Python libraries out there for computing spatial derivatives of optical flow?** I found this SO question that was somewhat similar [Lucas Kanade Optical Flow, Direction Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612018/lucas-kanade-optical-flow-direction-vector), and there is code the person wrote for computing spatial derivatives, but if at all possible I'd love a library rather than writing the code myself. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Why write the code yourself? Dump that person's code into a folder, add a `__init__.py`, and `import` it.

Comment: It's not really a library either...it's also code someone wrote themselves :P

Comment: A library in Python is just a folder with Python files in it. Also, isn't computing the optical flow's derivative a fairly simple task? You just need to smooth the data, approximate it with a polynomial, and then just differentiate the polynomial.

Comment: It very well could be; in my googling around the only results I've found for "derivatives of optical flow" have been 1) how to compute optical flow, and 2) very technical scholarly articles that are difficult to digest. I was hoping a library already existed, but in lieu of that I could write it myself if I could figure out what I'm doing in that regard. I understand the main idea, but the technical details I'm iffy on as I can't find a good explanation of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I see it (I've worked with optical flow a little bit):

You want to compute the individual partial derivatives of the optical flow field; one for the `x` direction, and one for the `y`.

I'd attempt to solve the problem like so:

- Split your flow array/matrix into two matrices: `x` and `y` flow.
- For each of those, you could go the naive route and just do a simple difference: `derivative = current_state - last_state`. But this approach is very messy, as the derivative will be sensitive to the slightest bit of error.
- To counter that, you could approximate one chunk of your data points (maybe a whole row?) with a regression curve that is easily differentiable, like a polynomial.

The just differentiate that approximated curve and you're good to go.

You could also just smooth individual matrices and do a naive difference, which should be much faster than approximating data points, but should be more tolerant to error.

Comment: This all makes a lot of sense. I suppose what I was looking for was for some conceptual connection between the high-level intuition (fit an easily-differentiable polynomial to the data) and the code to perform that task. I found the scipy.signal library which seems to have what I need, but now I'm running into Python TypeErrors. However, that probably deserves its own question. Thanks for your help! Also, love Blender! :)

Comment: Lol, no problem. I love this kind of stuff.