# TypeError in scipy.signal.sepfir2d

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, scipy, opticalflow

I'm attempting to calculate the derivatives of optical flow (as referenced [in my previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920988/python-library-for-computing-spatial-derivatives-of-optical-flow)) and am running into a TypeError when performing the calculation.

I first read the video in using OpenCV and use its optical flow methods to find the velocities. Then I use the scipy.signal library to run a gaussian filter over the velocities and calculate the derivatives.

```
cv.CalcOpticalFlowLK(prev_frame, curr_frame, (11, 11), velx, vely)

# ... convert velx and vely to numpy arrays ...

# Set up the gaussian filter and its derivative.
sigmaBlur = 1
sigmaGrey = 4
gBlurSize = 2 * np.around(2.5 * sigmaBlur) + 1
x = np.mgrid[1:gBlurSize + 1] - np.around((gBlurSize + 1) / 2)
gFilt = np.exp(-(x ** 2) / (2 * (sigmaBlur ** 2)))
gFilt /= np.sum(gFilt)
gxFilt = (-x / (sigmaBlur ** 2)) * gFilt

# Now calculate the derivative of the velocity.
res = scipy.signal.sepfir2d(velx, gxFilt, gFilt)

# ... 3 more calls to sepfir2d ... #
```

Unfortunately, at the call to sepfir2d, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type
```

The [documentation on the Scipy website](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sepfir2d.html#scipy.signal.sepfir2d) is extremely sparse, and I can't find many other examples of its use. All three arguments to sepfir2d are numpy arrays; velx is a matrix, and gxFilt and gFilt are both vectors of the same length (5 in this case, I think). **Any thoughts why the type error is occurring?**

Comment: For what it's worth `scipy.signal.seqfir2d` seems like a fairly odd way to do this... Any reason you couldn't use one of the more common routes, e.g. `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_gradient_magnitude`, etc?

Comment: I was actually debating using that, but I couldn't tell from the documentation alone if it was what I needed. Does it do the same thing as the code I wrote above? (I'm pretty new to the optical flow arena, so feel free to be as verbose as you like in explaining)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much testing (looking at the source for sepfir2d didn't help at all), it turns out the issue was in the fact that my `velx` and `vely` were using 32-bit floating point primitives, when they needed to be 64-bit. That fixed it.